# Multiple constructor called for one object

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
   private :

     int m_n;
     static int copyconst;
     static int copydest;

   public :

     A()
     {
       cout<<"Default constructor"<<endl;
     }

     A(int n):m_n(n)
     {
        cout<<"Param constructor"<<endl;
        cout<<m_n<<endl;
     }

     A(const A&obj1)
     {
       ++copyconst;
       cout<<"Copy constructor"<<endl;
     }

     A& operator=(const A&obj)
     {
         cout<<"Assignment operator"<<endl;
     }

     ~A()
     {
       ++copydest;
     }

};

int A::copyconst = 0;
int A::copydest = 0;

int main()
{
    A a = 0;
    a = 2;
}
```

Output -

```
Param constructor
0
Param constructor
2
Assignment operator
```

I am not able to understand why I am getting this output can any one help?

Comment: Add `explicit` keyword to constructor, to avoid such behavior.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48414780) answer clearly explains the reason. If you want to avoid unnecessary creation, you can add an assignment operator with int. Example here: https://godbolt.org/g/rvDBZU
You don't have to understand assembly. Just look for `call` and `jmp` instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you understand the first two prints.

```
Param constructor
0
```

This is because `A a = 0;` is a call to the constructor and not the assignment operator (as the object is being constructed)

When you do

```
a = 2;
```

then `2` is first converted to an object of type `A` because `A` can take int argument and you have not declared the constructor `explicit`. Hence you see this output

```
Param constructor
2
```

Next, the assignment operator is called to assign the value of `A(2)` to `a` and hence this output

```
Assignment operator
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got it

Answer (score 3):

> I am not able to understand why I am getting this output can any one help?

```
A a = 0;
```

is equivalent to:

```
A a(0);
```

That explains the first couple of lines of output.

```
a = 2;
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = A(2);
```

since there is no `operator=` function whose LHS is an `A` and the RHS is an `int`.

That explains the second couple of lines of output and the last line of output.